# BDE vs ADO Database Error handling

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am working on Delphi 7 + SQLserver

in **BDE** all database related related erros can be handled using **EDatabaseError**

```
try

//all database related operations

Except

on EDatabaseError do
begin
  showmessage(e.message)  
end;

End;
```

but in **ADO** i tried different examples and i am getting different errors like **EOleError/EDatabaseError/...**

I Tried below 2 points to raise errors in ADO and i got different errors

1) In sql server stored procedure i am raising error on first line. when i execute that procedure using **TADOStoredProc** in delphi i am getting **EOleError**.

2) In **TADOQuery** i have written a wrong sql statement so when i **open** **TADOQUery** i am getting **EDatabaseError**.

so now i am confused how to handle ADO errors. **i don't want to check for all the errors(EOleError,EDatabaseError,EAdoError...)** in each and every form so i have written 2 examples, 
Please suggest me which one is good. if both are wrong please give me a good example.

**Example 1:**
Here i am showing only one form in example so Delphi **Procedure HandleErrors** and **function GetErrorDescription** may look stupid. i don't want to write same piece of
code in all the forms. When it comes to real scenario i am gonna keep Delphi **Procedure HandleErrors** and **function GetErrorDescription** on different unit and use that unit all over the application.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Procedure HandleErrors(e: Exception );
    function GetErrorDescription : WideString;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TForm1.GetErrorDescription : WideString;
var
  LastErrorIndex : Integer;
begin
  LastErrorIndex  :=ADOConnection1.Errors.Count-1;
  Result:=ADOConnection1.Errors.Item[LastErrorIndex].Description;
  //Code            :=ADOConnection1.Errors.Item[LastErrorIndex].NativeError;
end;

procedure TForm1.HandleErrors(e: Exception);
var
  Code: Integer;
  ErrorDescription: WideString ;
begin
  if e is EOleError then
    ShowMessage(GetErrorDescription)
  else
  if e is EDatabaseError then
    ShowMessage(GetErrorDescription)
  else
  if e is EADOError then
    ShowMessage(GetErrorDescription)
  else
    ShowMessage(GetErrorDescription)
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
   // any database related operations
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      HandleErrors(E);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

**Example 2:**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,ADODB, StdCtrls, DB,COMOBJ;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LastErrorIndex : Integer;
begin
  try
   // any database related operations
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      LastErrorIndex  :=ADOConnection1.Errors.Count-1;
      ShowMessage(ADOConnection1.Errors.Item[LastErrorIndex].Description);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

which example is better. Can you please suggest a good one

Comment: "i don't want to check for all the errors in each and every form"  Well, that's what you are going to have to do if you insist on putting AdoConnections and datasets on your forms.  That's not the place for them (except in v. small testbeds).  Put (centralize) them in a DataModule and get used to accessing them from your forms.  Btw, my answer to your q yesterday showed you how to implement a centralized exception handler (see the reference to Application.OnException in the code).

Comment: @MartynA:(+1) i am working on a old application which is having lots and lots of datasets on forms and i dont want to move all those things to data module now. so i am checking how to handle exceptions. I will check Application.OnException. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MartynA: is it ok to go with example 2?

Comment: Try it, but first see if the exception block in your example 2 actually catches a syntax error in an AdoQuery's SQL when you try to open it.

Comment: @MartynA: i am mentioning about example 2 coz i want to use try and except blocks to handle exceptions. and i was not aware of application.onexception before i will try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you shouldn't scatter AdoConnections and datasets across multiple forms/  Instead you should put them in a datamodule then Use the datamodule's unit in your forms' units.  That way, you will be able to connect TDataSources and db-aware components on the form to the datamodule's datasets.

The other thing you can do is to install an application-wide exception handler to centralize your exception handling, if that's what you want to do.  Delphi's `Application` object has an `OnException` event which you can assign to your own exception handler using code like that shown below.

A downside of an application-wide exception handler is that it can be difficult in the `OnException` handler to identify which of your objects is actually responsible for causing the exception.

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    [...]
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure ApplicationException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
  public
  end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnException := ApplicationException;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ApplicationException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
var
  AErrors : Errors;
  AError : Error;
  i : Integer;
  S : String;
begin
  Caption := 'Exception';
  if E is EDatabaseError then begin
    AErrors := DataModule1.AdoQuery1.Connection.Errors;
    for i := 0 to AErrors.Count - 1 do begin
      AError := AErrors.Item[i];
      S := Format('Number: %d, NativeError: %d, source: %s, description: %s',
        [AError.Number, AError.NativeError, AError.Source, AError.Description]);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
    end;
  end;
end;
```